# Where does my dynamic programming approach goes wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this spoj problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/BYTESM2/

This is the code I've tried so far,

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int a[101][101],Table[101][101]={0};
int pickStones(int i,int j,int n,int m,int sum)
{
    int k,l,p;
    int stones=0;
    if(i>n||j>m||j<0)
    return 0;
    else if(i==n)
    return Table[i][j]=sum;
    else
    {
        if(Table[i][j]==0)
        {
            if(Table[i+1][j]==0)
        Table[i+1][j]=pickStones(i+1,j,n,m,sum+a[i][j]);
        if(Table[i+1][j-1]==0)
        Table[i+1][j-1]=pickStones(i+1,j-1,n,m,sum+a[i][j]);
        if(Table[i+1][j+1]==0)
        Table[i+1][j+1]=pickStones(i+1,j+1,n,m,sum+a[i][j]);
        stones=max(Table[i+1][j],Table[i+1][j-1]);
        stones=(max(stones,Table[i+1][j+1]));
        Table[i][j]=stones;
        }
        return Table[i][j];
    }
}
int main() {
    int t,n,m,l=0,h=0,max;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        max=a[0][0];
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        if(a[0][i]>max)
        {
            max=a[0][i];
            l=0;h=i;
        }
        printf("%d\n",pickStones(l,h,n,m,0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I get rid of the dynamic programming `Table[][]` array and store the results of `pickStones() in variables and implement the problem as plain recursion I get correct answer but I don't know where are the overlapping subproblems in this and how to store them to avoid computing again.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what dynamic programming is. wikipedia's entry on levenshtein distance is particularly clear: DP is just a recursion, there is no 'Table'. Unfortunately, the naive implementation usually runs forever, so in an efficient implementation previously computed results to subproblems are stored in a table. In that case, there is no recursive call, the table is filled from previously computed entries. You are mixing the idea and one of its possible implementations.

Comment: _DP is just a recursion, there is no 'Table'. Unfortunately, the naive implementation usually runs forever, so in an efficient implementation previously computed results to subproblems are stored in a table._ Exactly, that's what I am trying to achieve, storing up of precomputed results in Table[][] Array. The problem is I couldn't find overlapping subproblems and storing up of results,though I could get answer with naive recursion.

Comment: Would you please post the "correct" code without "Table"?

Comment: Every cell of your 'Table' will contain a number which is the maximum number of stones Harry can pick up starting from that cell on any path to the last row. Initially all cells are zero. Which cells can you fill without moving? Answer: all the cells of the last (h-th) row. Now, given the values of the last row you can calculate the numbers of row h-1 by taking the maximum of three accessible cells plus the number of stones on that cell. The subproblems are the number of stones you can pick up from row h...but that's already filled in, so no recursion. And you go backwards to the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a solution, or an explanation why your code won't work?
Anyway I will give my AC code first.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int w[200][200] = {0}, dp[200][200] = {0};
int t,r,c;
int main(){
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        cin >> r >> c;
        memset(w,0,sizeof(w)); memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
        for(int i=1; i<=r ;i++) for(int j=1; j<=c; j++) { 
            cin >> w[i][j]; dp[1][j] = w[1][j];
        }
        for(int i=2; i<=r; i++) for(int j=1; j<=c; j++) 
            dp[i][j] = w[i][j] + max(dp[i-1][j-1], max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j+1]));
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<=c;i++) ans = max(ans, dp[r][i]);
        cout << ans << endl;
    }
}
```

For your code

```
 max=a[0][0];
 for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
     if(a[0][i]>max)
     {
         max=a[0][i];
         l=0;h=i;
     }
```

Are you choosing the column of maximum stones at the first row to start?
This may not always be true.

Comment: keep a maximum line length of 80~120 characters or others will have to scroll to read your code